# Is there an issue with the Google Script function: getAs('application/pdf')?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a problem with this Google Script function: `getAs('application/pdf')` ?

Here is a bit of code that used to work before (maybe 4 to 6 weeks ago), and that is now failing.

I suspect that the `MailApp.sendEmail` function fails, because the PDF document to attach is not generated properly.

```
var pdfDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs('application/pdf');
MailApp.sendEmail(addresseeEmail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdfDoc});
```

Please note that those variables are all well defined and working (I used the log function to debug and check content)
 - copyId
 - addresseeEmail
 - subject
 - body

And the main Document identified by CopyId is existing well and being updated properly by the code above this step.

Thanks,

Comment: What's the error message?  If it's failing, there should be an error message.  Either a red alert message, or in the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT, at the bottom, it will state that the code failed.

Comment: I get an error from the line of the email sending, because of the attachment.

Comment: If it's a bug, you can report it at [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: That's not a bug, it's a syntax error... I doubt it ever really works (at least it shouldn't have ;-)

Comment: Hi, yes it did work, in the past, as I have been using it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The attachment must be an array of blobs (that's actually why the word "attachment" has an "s"), see [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) , so your script should be :

```
MailApp.sendEmail(addresseeEmail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: [pdfDoc]});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I still have the same error:
Here is the error notification:

Start 4/29/15 11:15 AM
Function: onFormSubmit
Error Message: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 228, file "Code")
Trigger: formSubmit
End: 4/29/15 11:15 AM

Where the line of code is:
MailApp.sendEmail(addresseeEmail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: [pdfDoc]});

If I do remove the: attachments: [pdfDoc], it is sending properly the email and this is why I think it's the problem.

Comment: I do not see either the generation of the PDF document from the initial document, so there must be something wrong in:
var pdfDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs('application/pdf');

Comment: If I do remove the attachments, I do get the email in which I did log some information using: 

Logger.log('pdfDoc: ' +pdfDoc);

and I got in the email:

pdfDoc: Blob

Comment: Morning all, I did replace the code by:
attachments: [DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs('application/pdf')]

but still receive this error message:
Start: 4/30/15 11:27 AM
Function: onFormSubmit
Error Message: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 228, file "Code")
Trigger: formSubmit
End: 4/30/15 11:27 AM

Comment: So nobody has any further suggestions or idea about the issue?

Comment: try to change your pdf conversion using MimeType instead :   var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById('file ID').getAs(MimeType.PDF); my test doc is working nicely

Comment: Hi Serge, thank you for your comment.
I then did replace this:
  var pdfDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs('application/pdf');
by that:
  var pdfDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  
Unfortunately, I got the same error notification from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com that says:
Details:
Start Function Error Message Trigger End
5/5/15 1:43 PM onFormSubmit We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 241, file "Code") formSubmit 5/5/15 1:43 PM

Comment: Hmmm... no idea. As I said, same code works for me without any error.

Comment: It may be some of our Google Acccount administration changes, I did report this problem. Frustrating not to know what is wrong!

Comment: Seems like it's a known issue at Google
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3206

Comment: For no reason, this is now working again. Should I suspecte a temp issue in the API or something else?